# Visually design a TableViewCell for a programatically created TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to programmatically add a `UITableView` and then programmatically add `UITableViewCells` to it.

I want the TableView to be created entirely in code but I want to create the prototype cells in storyboard.

From the tutorials I've seen, I usually place a TableView in storyboard and then place prototype cells inside it.

If I don't place a TableView in storyboard, where should I put the cells? Anywhere on the same view is ok?

Comment: create xib (not storyboard) then delete the view inside it and drag a tableviewcell and design in on that xib with cell in it, use custom class to handle coding. 1 xib per cell. you cannot add multiple cell to single xib. then use `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` to load in in `viewDidLoad` method `https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722`

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem. As you say, the "modern" way to do it is to create cell prototypes in the storyboard, but that requires that you define the table view in the storyboard as well.

I'd suggest using the `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` function to register nib (xib) files for each of your cell identifiers, adding nib files (actually xib files) to your project that contain those cells, and then dequeuing cells via their reuse identifier as normal.